# What is the equation for "beff", i.e., "Gain Factor in Saturation" in BSIM4?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, analog, integrated-circuit, cadence

Using the device parameter list in Cadence, I found out that ID follows this equation exactly:

```
ID = 1/2 * beff * vgt**2
```

I also found out that `beff` is not linear, as expected.
I checked the BSIM4 documentation but either I cannot find the equation or I do not know the name(s) used to describe this parameter.

I need the equation because one analytical formula that describes my circuit has this term
$$
\mu_{0}C_{ox}\frac{W}{L}
$$

So, I would appreciate it if anyone can point me where to look.

Comment: Not relevant to your question, I don't think you have to know the equation for beff. You may either center your design based on favorable gm-ID curves, or begin with simple square-law model to derive initial guesses for the circuit's operating points.

Comment: Hi, actually I did try to extract 'beff' using gm/Id method, i.e., sweeping VGS at a particular L. But I the 'beff' I got is not correct.